# jQuery color scaling html table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I'm working on adding better visualization to data tables that I have so that the highest numbers in that column will have a green CSS background, and the lowest values in that column will have a red CSS background.

I've come pretty far, I am basically down to the last bit. I'm a native PHP dev, so I may be messing up the integer comparison as well as not doing the final jQuery selector correctly. The code selects all the elements in the same column, finds the min and max, calculates the step value, and calculates how many steps above the minimum the current element is. All I need to do now is apply a css class based on the steps. It will be something like values in the 0-5% range will have css group 0, 5-10 will have css group 1, 10-15 group 2, 95-100 group 20. All that css is on the fiddle. I am successfully applying a CSS class, but not to a single cell, it does it for the whole column

```
$(document).on('click', '#dvData td.color', function() {
    var ndx = $(this).index() + 1;
    //alert('Val of ndx: ' + ndx);
    var thisCol = $('#dvData td:nth-child(' +ndx+ ')');
    var arr = thisCol.slice(1, thisCol.length);

    var columnDataArr = new Array();
    alert("Number of rows: " + arr.length);
        //alert("First Row: " + arr[0].innerHTML);
    for(var i = 0, x = arr.length; i < x; i++){
        columnDataArr[i] = arr[i].innerHTML;
    }
    var colorsArray = ["63BE7B","72C27B","82C77C","91CB7D","A1D07E","B1D47F","C0D980","D0DD81","DFE282","EFE683","FFEB84","FFDE82","FED280","FDC47D","FDB87B","FCAA78","FB9D75","FB9073","FA8370","F9776E","F8696B"];

    var max = Math.max.apply(Math, columnDataArr),
        min = Math.min.apply(Math, columnDataArr),
        range = max - min,
        step_val = range/100;
        alert("Step Value:" + step_val);

    for(var i = 0, x = arr.length; i < x; i++){
        var thisPercentile = parseInt((columnDataArr[i] - min) / step_val);
        alert("Percentile:" + thisPercentile);     
        switch ( thisPercentile ) {
            // yes this looks terrible, but i can't seem to get the case to work
            // with: case(thisPercentile) <= 5:
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
                alert("Below 10th Percentile");
                break;
            case parseInt(90):
                alert("90th Percentile");
                //arr[2].addClass('group10') // doesn't work
                break;
        }
    }
    arr.addClass('group20');
});
```

So the two issues are how to deal with passing a Range to a switch statement (or giving up and using ifs and else ifs), and what the correct selector is to target the current table cell. I have [my code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Luwyyxr/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your value range goes from 0-100 and your group names go from group0-group20, you can do a bit of math and forego the switch/if statement entirely.

If you get the floor of ( value / 5 ), you will end up with 0 for 0-4, 1 for 5-9, ... 19 for 95-99, 20 for 100.

After getting the floor value, you can concatenate the result with the group name and add the result clsas like below:

Note:  You created a vanilla JS array with splice, so you'll need to wrap arr[i] with $( ) to turn it into a jQuery object.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Luwyyxr/2/

```
    for(var i = 0, x = arr.length; i < x; i++){
        var thisPercentile = parseInt((columnDataArr[i] - min) / step_val);
        alert("Percentile:" + thisPercentile);     

        // added this stuff
        var gnum = Math.floor( thisPercentile/5 );  // returns 0 for 0-4, 1 for 5-9, ...
        //alert("Group Num: " + gnum);
        $(arr[i]).addClass('group'+gnum);  // appends class to array index
    }
```

Comment: Beautiful -- yeah, can't believe I missed a $().. actually yes I can. You don't by chance also happen to know how to change this so that it assigns color based on rank, not percent of max?

Comment: Hmm, it should be something similar.  What's the definition of rank?

Comment: For example I might have the dataset 5, 90, 98, 99, 99, I'd want to mark 5 as red, 90 as orange, 98 as yellow, 99's as green -- so 5 would be the bottom or top rank, 99 would be the top or bottom rank, the middle "rank" would be the median

Comment: Would the top rank always get the same color/class?  Also, how many possible values would be in the array?  This should be pretty easy - 1.  sort the array 2.  iteratte through the sorted array and add class.  Done!

Comment: Top rank always means green css. There's always a different number of rows in the column. Yeah that does sound simple when you put it that way

Comment: Cool.  Give it a shot, and if you need help, just update your fiddle and post back.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will distinguish between 20 different numbers before assigning 2 numbers the same colors. It works with percentile (e.g. the percent of items it is greater than or equal to) to assign a color. The top value would always get the same class, and the lowest would always get the same class. The numbers in between would depend on each other to get a class assigned.

```
for(var i = 0, x = columnDataArr.length; i < x; i++){
    var greaterThan = 0;
    var curNum = columnDataArr[i];
    for(var j = 0, x = columnDataArr.length; j < x; j++){
        if(curNum <= columnDataArr[j]){
            greaterThan += 1;
        }

    }

    var percentile = Math.round((greaterThan*100)/columnDataArr.length);
    var group = Math.round(percentile/5);
    $(arr[i]).addClass('group'+group);
}
```

And heres a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7Luwyyxr/4/